# Why does one of my QtWidgets not appear?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

My GLWidget (inherited from QtOpenGL.QGLWidget) does not appear on screen, while it should be visible at the right of the other widgets. However, when I switch from an horizontal layout:

```
 layout_final = Qtgui.QHBoxLayout()
```

to a vertical one:

```
 layout_final = Qtgui.QVBoxLayout()
```

my GL widget does appear under the other widgets, but I want it to be on the right of the other widgets.

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()


        # create layout
        layout_before_final = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout_final = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout1 = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox('Set HDF5 file')
        self.groupBox1 = QtGui.QGroupBox('Current HDF5 file')

        # instance widgets
        # first box
        self.setH5Button = QtGui.QPushButton('set H5')
        self.currentH5LineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit('')
        layout.addWidget(self.setH5Button, 0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.currentH5LineEdit, 0, 1)
        self.groupBox.setLayout(layout)

        # second box
        self.channelsLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Channel')
        self.channelsComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()
        self.levelsLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Level')
        self.levelsComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()      


        layout1.addWidget(self.channelsLabel, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        layout1.addWidget(self.channelsComboBox, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        layout1.addWidget(self.levelsLabel, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        layout1.addWidget(self.levelsComboBox, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox1.setLayout(layout1)        

        # create QWidget to gather the two previous boxes

        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout_before_final.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        layout_before_final.addWidget(self.groupBox1)   

        self.widget.setLayout(layout_before_final)

        # GL widget
        self.widgetGL = MyWidget()

        # create a final widget to add the GL widget
        self.finalWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout_final.addWidget(self.widgetGL)
        layout_final.addWidget(self.widget)   

        self.finalWidget.setLayout(layout_final)                


        self.setCentralWidget(self.finalWidget)

        self.setWindowTitle('PyPractis')
        self.resize(640, 480)      





def main():
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* it's happening, but it appears to be caused by the GL widget preferentially collapsing horizontally (giving up it's space to the other elements). You can easily override this behaviour however, by specifying the stretch priority when adding the element:

```
layout_final.addWidget(self.widgetGL, stretch=1)
```

This results in the following layout:

[image]